# Filtering by Gender on targeting_spec

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

How to set the gender in Facebook Marketing API targetting spec?

I've tried setting the gender but i'm getting gender is not a valid target spec field error.

```
targeting_spec = {"geo_locations":
                {
                    "location_types": ["recent"],
                    "custom_locations": [
                        {
                            "latitude": 14.5764,
                            "longitude": 121.0851,
                            "radius": 17
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "age_min": 18,
                "age_max": 35,
                "gender": "male", // Setting gender, doesn't work
                "flexible_spec": [
                    {
                        "interests": [
                            {"id": "6002998074973", "name": "BTS"}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "interests": [
                            {"id": "6005882720291", "name": "Data Science"}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It should be **genders**.

The values are:

```
gender: [0] # All
gender: [1] # Men
gender: [2] # Women
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting/:

> genders: array
>
> - 1=male
> - 2=female.
> - Defaults to all.

For example:

```
targeting: {
  genders: [1]
  ...
```